# Find errors in data with R

Tags: r

**Problem:** One  company  has  obvious  errors  in  data,  find  it  and  exclude  from  the further analysis.

Data is factors.

Can someone help me with any easy way to find errors in the data?
the companys numbers is in column "custnr". So it is from that column we will find errors in data.Some tips?

```
  zon      age custnr agree       dur   claim  skadkost claimfreq
1   1       0     15      2  1.585216       0        0  0.0000000
2   1       0    145     47 12.062971     377   294556 31.2526668
3   1       0    184      6  3.321013       4    22152  1.2044518
4   1       0    226      9  5.336071       5      882  0.9370190
5   1       0    231      6  4.865161       1    67395  0.2055431
6   1       0    385      4  5.998631       1     8869  0.1667047
```

Comment: What do you mean errors? NA values? Negative values?

Comment: I do not know, the dataset is quite large and they only said find "Obvious" errors. Which for me is not "Obvious". But it applies to both I would say. I do not want any negative values or NA values. @KiprasKančys

Comment: You could try doing a boxplot of each column to see if there be any obvious outliers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove `NA` values.

```
dataNoNa <- data[!is.na(data$custnr), ]
```

To remove negative values.

```
dataClean <- dataNoNa[dataNoNa$custnr > 0, ]
```